# Spark top horizontal menu for mobile app

Tags: flash, apache-flex, menu, flex-spark

I'm new to Flash. In my mobile app I need a simple horizontal menu (or toolbar) with 3-4 items on top of the screen.
ViewMenu is perfect for this task, but I couldn't find a way to display it on top - is it possible?
As far as I understand, mx:MenuBar is not available for mobile. Are there any other components that can be used as menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spark Callout Component. This an example screenshot from the [ActionScript reference docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Callout.html):

[image]

The contents of the Callout can be a View containing a List of menu items.

Callout was introduced in Flex 4.6.

Here are two tutorials on how to implement it:

[Add a callout container to a mobile application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb706aafb086131b54b6ec7-8000.html).

[Callout component sample with source.](http://devgirl.org/2011/10/17/flex-mobile-development-callout-component-sample-with-source/)

Comment: It's a nice component, but not exactly what I wanted..
I ended up writing my own floating menu component.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its called an ActionBar:

Docs from Adobe - [ActionBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ActionBar.html)

Blog example: [Styling Action Bar](http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/05/tutorial-styling-the-actionbar.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that I need popup menu (floating). When ActionBar is shown, it resizes the view and shifts its content down..